# How can I increase the size of the images within my ImageButtons?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scale, imagebutton

In a nutshell I'm looking for my dotted box image to fill the view. I had 60x60 image Buttons in my medium screen layout. In my large screen layout my buttons have appeared tiny so I've increased them to 100x100. The images within these buttons will not stretch. Is it possible to stretch these images or replace them with bigger ones?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This combined with specifiying your own dimensions rather than wrap_content does the job.

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know people don't like this because it renders slower, but I think LinearLayout is going to be the way to go. When you use RelativeLayout, two devices with XHDPI or LDPI may still render images differently due to difference in screen size/resolution.

Using LinearLayout will force the images to be the same size relative to the screen. The one caveat is screens will vary from 1.5:1 to 1.77:1 (personal experience, might be a little off), stretching some images about 10%.

Comment: There are many invisible views within my layout. The quantity of views and the precision of their placement ruled out LinearLayout for me. I'm hoping I can find a way of making this image bigger without having to re-do my layouts from scratch, this is one of 6 layouts I have made. Really isn't much to ask of android to have the ability to stretch images to their view or swap images based on screen size. :(